# Interpreting the regex

Tags: python, regex, dataframe

This is my dataframe...

```
Status1Day  labels
0       0.0
1   RAC 13  1.0
2   WL 14   0.0
3   GNWL 15 0.0
4   RLWL 16 0.0
5   PQWL 17 0.0
6   REGRET/ 0.0
7       0.0
8       1.0
```

Running the below line in python

```
df['Status1Day'].replace(regex=True, inplace=True, to_replace=r'[^W/L\d\s,].*', value= r'0')
```

Result is

```
Status1Day  labels
0       0.0
1   0   1.0
2   WL 14   0.0
3   0   0.0
4   0   0.0
5   0   0.0
6   0   0.0
7       0.0
8       1.0
```

Can someone please help on what r'[^W/L\d\s,].*' does?

Comment: Please tag Python.

Answer (score 0):

`[^W/L\d\s,].*` means `any character that is not W, /, L, digit, whitespace, ','(comma) and all characters after that (except \n)`.

Basically this line of code doesn't change start of string which contains `W, /, L, whitespace and ',' (comma)` and changes everything else to 0.

Also you can see explanantion in regex101.com.